# Get the connection speed when using HttpAsyncClient

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

When use synchronous `HttpClient`, it's very easy to get the time of one request, just put `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after the `execute()` method.

But when it comes to `HttpAsyncClient`, the `execute()` is asynchronous , which will just put the task into the queue. So I don't know how to get the start time of a connection.

The end time of a connection is easy, just call `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the `OnComplete()` method of the class instance `FutureCallback<HttpResponse>`

Both the synchronous `HttpClient` and asynchronous `HttpAsyncClient` have three phases, `ConnectRequestTime`, `ConnectTime`, `SocketTime`. All requests will be queued before actually get execution. if we call `long start=System.currentTimeMillis()` in `HttpAsyncRequestProducer.html#generateRequest()`, we just take a note of the start time when the request is sent to the internal queue, so at last what you get is  `ConnectRequestTime`+`ConnectTime`+`SocketTime`, when you do a benchmark to test a batch requests, it's fine, but to test each single request, we need to substract `ConnectRequestTime`.

So my real question is how to get the time of `ConnectRequestTime`?

Answer (score 0):

[HttpAsyncRequestProducer.html#generateRequest()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/apidocs/org/apache/http/nio/protocol/HttpAsyncRequestProducer.html#generateRequest()) should be the right place.

You might also want to have a look at [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/benchmark/httpclient/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/benchmark/ApacheHttpAsyncClient.java) as an example of how to squeeze maximum performance out of Apache HttpAsyncClient when doing micro benchmarking.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try

Comment: After I read through the source code, I find that this source code can only calculate the total time of `n` requests, it's not able to calculate the time of each single async HTTP request

Comment: Huh? I gave you an answer where to put code to record start time. The example was to demonstrate performance optimizations for micro-benchmarking. You still need to do what you need to do by yourself.

Comment: Both the synchronous `HttpClient` and asynchronous `HttpAsyncClient` have three phases, `ConnectRequestTime`, `ConnectTime`, `SocketTime`. All requests will be queued before actually get execution. if you call `long start=System.currentTimeMillis()` in `HttpAsyncRequestProducer.html#generateRequest()`, you just get the start time when the request is sent to the internal queue, so what you get is  `ConnectRequestTime`+`ConnectTime`+`SocketTime`, when you do a benchmark to test a batch requests, it's fine, but to test each single request, you need to substract `ConnectRequestTime`